# Access \title variable when redefining \ps@plain

Tags: header-footer, titles

I want to have fancy footer. I am trying to achieve this by redefining the `\ps@plain` command, which redefines `\@oddfoot` and `\@evenfoot`.

The problem I ran into is that the variables `\title` and `\@title` do not render the value set in `doc.tex` file:

style.sty:

```
\def\ps@plain{
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}%
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{}%
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\title\@title}   % Footer is empty 
  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}%
}
```

doc.tex:

```
...
\title{My document}
\begin{document}
```

I tried defining `\title` as global variable in my `style.sty`, but without any luck:

```
\global\let\@title\@empty
\global\let\title\relax
```

I am new to LaTeX and I don't really understand how variable scopes work. Any hints would be appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `\@title` container is discarded by the `article` class after it has been used by `\maketitle`. You could jump the gun and redefine `\title` to have also an optional argument for the footer:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % just for the example

\makeatletter
\def\title{\@dblarg\niekas@title}
\def\niekas@title[#1]#2{%
  \gdef\@title{#2}% for \maketitle
  \gdef\niekas@keep@title{#1}% for the footer
}

\def\ps@plain{%
  \let\@mkboth\@gobbletwo
  \renewcommand{\@oddhead}{}%
  \renewcommand{\@evenhead}{}%
  \renewcommand{\@evenfoot}{\reset@font\small\niekas@keep@title\hfil\thepage}%
  \renewcommand{\@oddfoot}{\@evenfoot}%
}
\pagestyle{plain} % apply the changes
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\author{Niekas}
\title[A short version]
  {A very long and boring title telling what
  should be in the paper instead of clobbering
  the title}

\maketitle

\lipsum[1-12]

\end{document}
```

Of course you can still say

```
\title{A title that is good in the footer}
```

and not specify the optional argument.

[image]